# Multicolumn and multirow (tabularx)

Tags: tabularx, multirow, multicolumn

I have a  table, and it should be also border betwen C and D in the second row and border between 12 and 13. How to do that?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[russian]{babel}   
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}   
\begin{document}     

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X|X|X|с|с| }    
\hline    
\multirow{2}*{N} & \multirow{2}*{номер} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Технические харектеристики} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Поверка} \\   \cline{3-6}     
   &       & A & B & C  & D   \\ \hline     
 1 & 235  & ла & ба & 12  & 13   \\ \hline     
\end{tabularx}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this does not compile!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this?

`\multicolumn` is tricky with vertical rules (rather don't use them at all!)

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[russian]{babel}   
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}   
\begin{document}     

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|c|c|}
\hline    
\multirow{2}*{N} & \multirow{2}*{номер} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Технические харектеристики} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Поверка} \\   \cline{3-6}     
   &       & A & B & C  & D   \\ \hline     
 1 & 235  & ла & ба & 12  & 13   \\ \hline     
\end{tabularx}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "(rather don't use them at all!)" - what would you recommend to use instead of \multicolumn ?

Comment: @Lucky_girl: well, I meant don't use vertical rules. `\multicolumn` is alright. Vertical rules do not really improve readability